# Changing text color of an html link after opened in new tab?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html, css

I'm working on my Asp.net (C#) project, I have an html link in my `Dashboard.aspx` page that the user can open it in new tab, and i  want to change the text color of the link after the user clicked it or opened it in a new tab, More details:

In my `Dashboard.aspx`:

```
<a href="~/SomePage.aspx" id="link" runat="server" style="color: blue;"></a>
```

I want to change the text color of this link to `red` after the user clicked it or opened it in a new tab, i have tried this:

```
<a href="~/SomePage.aspx" id="link" runat="server" onclick="Clicked()" style="color: blue;"></a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Clicked() {
        document.getElementById("link").style.color = "red";
    }
</script>
```

But it works just when i click on the link (left click on the mouse), and does nothing when i click on the right button of the mouse and open it on a new tab, i mean: i want the color to be changed after the user opened the link in a new tab (In general: after the user has browsed the link), how can i do that?

The reason I want to do this is: After the user visits this link and returns to `Dashboard.aspx` to browse more links, he will be able to identify which links he has already visited - those with the red color.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you initially set the color via an inline style and the only thing that can override an inline style is an `!important` directive, which you shouldn't use anyway.

> The reason I want to do this is: After the user visits this link and
>   returns to Dashboard.aspx to browse more links, he will be able to
>   identify which links he has already visited - those with the red
>   color.

This will happen without your involvement because all browsers color-code links based on whether the URL they point to is in the browser's history (in other words, you've been there already). You can certainly customize the colors and other styling that is applied with standard CSS pseudo-classes:

```
a:link    { color:blue; }  /* Unvisited link color */
a:visited { color:red; }  /* Visited link color */
```

But, if you want to have more granular control, just set up two classes - one for the initial look and one for the after look. Then just use JS to swap the classes  with the DOM element's [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) API.

Here's an example:

```js
document.querySelector("p").addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.classList.remove("before");
  this.classList.add("after");
});
```

```css
.before { color:red; }
.after { color:blue; }
```

```html
<p class="before">Click me</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove inline style from `a` element, and add your styles in css, because like @Scott Marcus said, the inline styles has priority over css styles. So add style for normal link (not visited) and add style for visited link `:visited`. Run the snippet bellow, and if you have not visited code.org yet, the link is blue, otherwise it will be red.

To visit right click on the link and click on 'open in new tab' (chrome), because just clicking did not open the link in the snippet.

```css
a#link {
  color: blue;
}

a#link:visited {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://code.org" target="_blank" id="link">Link</a>
```